# bash parsing multi word string to JSON value

Tags: json, bash, github

A bash script for creating new github repos from the command line works unless given multi word descriptions:

```
REPOSTRING={\"name\":\"$1\",\"description\":\"$2\",\"license_template\":\"mit\"}
echo $REPOSTRING
curl https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=xxx -d $REPOSTRING
```

Calling the script `script testrepo testdescription` works as expected, but `script testrepo "description with spaces"` errors out with:

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: with
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 33
```

It appears the spaces are breaking up the `REPOSTRING` even though the `echo` in the script shows `REPOSTRING` as

```
{"name":"testrepo","description":"description with spaces","license_template":"mit"}
```

with the spaces appearing within double quotes.

Is there something special I need to do with the `$2` in the `REPOSTRING` assignment that I'm missing?  I've attempted it as

```
REPOSTRING={\"name\":\"$1\",\"description\":\""$2"\",\"license_template\":\"mit\"}
```

but quoting `$2` explicitly caused no change.

Comment: Quote your variable expansions. Also use `declare -p REPOSTRING` to see what the value actually is instead of `echo`. Also use `set -x` to see what commands are *actually* being run to debug script issues like this.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or system, such that your own code should use names with at least one lower-case letter; see the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (fourth paragraph), keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: That said -- if your content contains spaces, you need to quote correctly on expanding the variable, not just assigning it. Be sure you use `"$REPOSTRING"`, not `$REPOSTRING`, when leveraging this later, and run your code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: @Etan & Charles Thanks for the tips, I'll definitely keep those in mind when writing shell scripts in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be guaranteed that output will be accepted by JSON parser, use a tool that knows how to generate JSON -- such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```
repo_string=$(jq --arg name "$1" \
                 --arg description "$2" \
                 '.name=$name | .description=$description' \
                 <<<'{"license_template": "mit"}')
```

Other approaches might have trouble with conditions including:

- Literal `"` characters (which need to be escaped to be treated as data rather than syntax
- Literal backslashes (which will be treated as syntax rather than data when seen by a JSON parser unless, again, escaped).

Comment: I would take it a step further and eliminate the here string in favor of letting `jq` generate everything: `jq -n --arg name "$1" --arg description "$2" '{"license_template": "mit"} | .name=$name | .description=$description'`, or just specify a single literal without the pipeline of filters.

Comment: That did the trick, though I used the syntax from @chepner.  Thanks for the introduction to jq, I'm sure it'll come in handy in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You have to quote the string assignment:

```
REPOSTRING="{\"name\":\"$1\",\"description\":\"$2\",\"license_template\":\"mit\"}"
```

Comment: This still won't work right with all strings -- think about what happens if a description contains literal quotes.

Comment: true but unlikely according to the examples

Comment: Writing code that can handle only the scenarios one expects to occur is a sure way to have bugs when encountering the unexpected.